# SQL Server Storing DateTime as Integer

Tags: sql, datetime, data-warehouse

I am adding some tables to a data warehouse and want to store datetime information into an int field (the time part is not important to me)

Note that I'm not storing as 20150123, I just store it as pure integer using

```
CAST(field as int)
```

that stores 2015-06-18 12:57:47.833 as 42172

I can easily add a day by +1 and add a week by adding 7 to the field. however adding a month is not straight forward.
Also whenever I need a date representation of the data, I can cast it to datetime.

Just want to know what pros and cons you see on this?

Comment: Date times are stored as integers under the hood, why force it?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?  If you want to store a date, just use the `DATE` datatype.

Comment: Why not use the inherent power and functions of SQL and store it as Date?  And then perform date functions on it so you don't have deal with months and number of days in months issues, etc.  Explain your proposed reasoning more.

Comment: `DateAdd(Month, 1, <dateColHere>)` -- adds 1 month to the <dateColHere> date.  Using the `DateAdd()` SQL function lets you do all of this... I'm with the above comments that there really isn't a good reason to store as an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting between an `int` and a `datetime` works just fine. It's well defined what the conversion does, so there is nothing mysterious going on that might suddenly change or stop working.

Let's look at some aspects:

- Comparable: Yes; you can still just compare the numbers to tell which date is earlier.
- Sortable: Yes; you can simply sort on the `int` and it's sorted by date.
- Readable: No; you have to convert it to a `datetime` to make any sense of it.
- Self-explanatory: No; you have to know what the number represents to do anything with it.
- Portable: Yes; you can do the same conversion in any system that supports date arithmetics.

You can for example do the same conversion from `int` to `DateTime` in C#:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(42172);
```

When it comes to storage space, there isn't really any advantage. An `int` uses four bytes and a `datetime` uses eight bytes. If you really need to preserve space, you should rather use the `date` type, which uses only three bytes.

Comment: casting the int to datetime is not giving me the hours/minutes detail, any idea how to get it back from the converted integer? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Cons**: when you cast it to int, you loose the time portion of the datetime, and end up with only the date part stored. You save 4 bytes (8 bytes for datetime, 4 bytes for int), but you lose precision. By casting to date, you loose just as much precision, but you save 5 bytes (3 bytes for date). So if the goal is saving storage space I would recommend cast to date.

If the objective is easy manipulation, use the `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` functions, they work on both date and datetime. Not as straightforward as `+1` or `-7`, but not much more complex either, and basically the only way to add months or years without extensive coding.

**Pros**: if you work with Excel no conversion is needed between Excel and the database, this is Excel's default date format, made readable by Excel, with all Excel's date functions working on it